# Can Access replace data information in an upload?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a project in Access where we are using tables that have the customers information.  These tables were created by downloading as Excel from another site of ours and then uploading to the Access program.
The problem is that the information on our other site changes sometimes, and we really don't know what has changed on our existing information.  When we append a new Excel download it will add customeraccountID's that are not on the table yet, but I need a way of finding out if there are any changes to the existing information. 
I have tried an update query, but that makes forms that have a relationship to the customer information tables not show the detail section.  From what I have researched, this is possibly due to the update query making the updated table read only.
I have taken an made a query that gives me a list of all the duplicates between the newly downloaded Excel  and the existing table, but now I need some way to find if there is any changes.  There are 60 columns where there could be changes.
We are not against manually updated our tables if we can find a way of finding out what has changed.
I have considered downloading the duplicates report to excel and running a formula using exact(a2:a61,b2:b61), but then I would have to copy that formula to every other row through thousands of rows.  I have no preference to whether we find the changes by Excel or Access.
The best way would be to have Access replace the information when appending the new information, not just drop the duplicates.  Which would mean having Access replace the existing data when appending.  Is that possible or can a report be created that shows where the information differs?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking, and I really tried to make sense of it. You can improve this immensely: [edit] your question, start by breaking it up from one large wall of text into readable paragraphs, and then try clearly stating the problem you're having. When you're doing so, remember that we have no background information to consider other than what you're providing in your question itself and we can't read your mind or see your screen, and describe the problem from that standpoint.

Comment: Is `customeraccountID` a primary key, present in both Excel and Access, which you can use to identify whether one of the Excel rows is a new record or a potential update of an existing Access record?

Comment: Yes customeraccountID is the primary key.  That is how it is determining whether it is a new record.  The problem is that information in the other 60 columns may have changed making it a potential update.  How do I get Access to update without causing my forms to not show the detail area.  I have tried using an update query, but that affects those forms.  I am not sure, but I think it is because it makes the table read only.

Comment: If the same `customeraccountID` is present in both Access and Excel, does the Excel record always contain the information you want to keep?

Comment: Yes.  The Excel sheet would have the most up-to-date information.

Comment: Can you delete the Access records whose `customeraccountID` is present in Excel, and then append the Excel rows to Access?  With that approach, you needn't invest effort to reconcile duplicates --- just delete them from Access and pull in the latest Excel versions of them.